# ext.net.row editing ,how to triger update event fire ( OnBeforeRecordUpdated)

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I have a srote like this

```
 <ext:Store ID="strPos" runat="server" AutoSync="false" OnReadData="StoreChange_Event" 
                OnBeforeRecordUpdated="StorePostGuncelle" OnBeforeRecordInserted="StorePostEkle"
                AutomaticResponseValues="false" OnBeforeRecordDeleted="StorePosSil">
```

I can ınserting values like that way,

```
 grid.store.insert(0, r);
                     #{strPos}.sync();

                     grid.store.reload();
```

but the problem is when updating the value .when clcik the row ,open row editor,then I clcik the update button but no event fire .(I wanna fireOnBeforeRecordUpdaten event ).

I have already tried this ,

```
  <Plugins>
            <ext:RowEditing ID="RowEditing1" runat="server" CancelBtnText="İptal" SaveBtnText="Kaydet"  ClicksToEdit="1"  TriggerEvent="#{strPos}.sync();#{strPos}.reload();" >
      </ext:RowEditing>
   </Plugins>
```

and this one

```
<Plugins>
            <ext:RowEditing ID="RowEditing1" runat="server" CancelBtnText="İptal" SaveBtnText="Kaydet"  ClicksToEdit="1"   SaveHandler="#{strPos}.sync();#{strPos}.reload();" SaveHandler="" >
            </ext:RowEditing>
        </Plugins>
```

but change nothing.
thank you

**
 it is availbale this.up('gridpanel').store.removeAt(recordIndex);  and insert method but where is the update method.
EDITED: complete example ;

```
 <ext:XScript ID="XScript1" runat="server">
       <script>
           function addPlant(btn) {
               // Create a model instance
                 var grid = #{GridPanel1};
               grid.editingPlugin.cancelEdit();

                 var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
                    Adi: 'pos bilgisi',
                    Id:'0'


                } ,'Pos');

                     grid.store.insert(0, r);
                     #{strPos}.sync();

                     grid.store.reload();    

         // grid.editingPlugin.startEditByPosition({ row: 0, column: 1 });

           }

    </script>
    </ext:XScript>
<ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" Scroll="Vertical" runat="server" Title="Pos tanımlamalrı" 
        Height="200">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store ID="strPos" runat="server" AutoSync="false" OnReadData="StoreChange_Event" OnAfterStoreChanged="store_change"
                OnBeforeRecordUpdated="StorePostGuncelle" OnBeforeRecordInserted="StorePostEkle"
                AutomaticResponseValues="false" OnBeforeRecordDeleted="StorePosSil">


                <Model>
                    <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" Name="Pos">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Id" Type="Int" SortDir="ASC"  />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Adi" Type="String" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
        <TopBar>
            <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Pos ekle" Handler="addPlant" Icon="Add" />
                </Items>
            </ext:Toolbar>
        </TopBar>
        <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column ID="Column7" runat="server" Text="Id" DataIndex="Id" Flex="1">
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column ID="Column8" runat="server" Text="Banka adı" DataIndex="Adi" Flex="1">
                    <Editor>
                        <ext:TextField ID="txtAd" runat="server" AllowBlank="false" />
                    </Editor>
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:ImageCommandColumn ID="ImageCommandColumn1" runat="server" Width="30" Sortable="false">
                    <Commands>
                        <ext:ImageCommand Icon="Decline" ToolTip-Text="Delete Plant" CommandName="delete">
                        </ext:ImageCommand>
                    </Commands>
                    <Listeners>
                        <Command Handler="this.up('gridpanel').store.removeAt(recordIndex);#{strPos}.sync();" />
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="rowSelectionModel1" runat="server">
            </ext:RowSelectionModel>
        </SelectionModel>
        <Plugins>
            <ext:RowEditing ID="RowEditing1" runat="server"  CancelBtnText="İptal" SaveBtnText="Kaydet"  ClicksToEdit="0"  SaveHandler="#{strPos}.sync();" >

            </ext:RowEditing>
        </Plugins>
    </ext:GridPanel>
```

and the code behind is here

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
            {
                strPos.DataSource = ps.Getir();
                strPos.DataBind();


            }


        }

        protected void StoreChange_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            strPos.DataSource = ps.Getir();
            strPos.DataBind();


        }

        protected void store_change(object sender, AfterStoreChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            strPos.DataSource = ps.Getir();
            strPos.DataBind();


        }

        public void StorePostEkle(object sender, BeforeRecordInsertedEventArgs e)
        {





            // string ss = e.Record.ToString();

            Pos pss = e.Object<Pos>();

            ps.Ekle(pss);

            X.Msg.Notify("store", "storea veri eklendi" + e.Record).Show();




            //  GridPanel1.Reload();


        }



        protected void StorePosSil(object sender, BeforeRecordDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            X.Msg.Notify("store", "storea dan veri, silindi " + e.Record).Show();


            Pos pss = e.Object<Pos>();
            try
            {
                ps.Sil(pss.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }



        }

        protected void StorePostGuncelle(object sender, BeforeRecordUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {

            X.Msg.Notify("store", "storea güncellendi " + e.Record).Show();
            Pos pss = e.Object<Pos>();

            // Pos pss = JSON.Deserialize<Pos>(e.ToString());
            ps.Guncelle(pss);
```

Comment: Well, when you insert a record, it is not an update operation, it is an insert operation.

Comment: sorry I coulndt understand u well,I inserted yes thats right trying to call update function  OnBeforeRecordUpdated="StorePostGuncelle"

Comment: Do you need OnBeforeRecordUpdated to be fired on insertion a new record?

Comment: no just need a update function when AI click the update button  thats all.

Comment: should I use OnAfterRecordUpdated event ?

Comment: to call this one        <ext:RowEditing ID="RowEditing1" runat="server" CancelBtnText="İptal" SaveBtnText="Kaydet"  ClicksToEdit="1"   SaveHandler="#{strPos}.sync();#{strPos}.reload();" SaveHandler="" >
            </ext:RowEditing> to fire savehandler???

Comment: Could you provide a full example of your scenario, please?

Comment: yep I put my full example ,

Comment: @user2460637 post the solution as an answer please. this is a Q&A Site not a Q&Solved but noone knows how Site

Comment: Yes u are right ,I was make mistake I just forget the enable row editor plugin,after enable ,it works fine